# Checking if an expression is balanced in terms of parantheses

Tags: java, nested, stack

I'm trying to check if an expression is balanced in terms of its parentheses , my program should output the appropriate messages as follows: (I'm reading the expression from a file)

If for every ")" there is an "(" then it's balanced.
If there is a ")" with no "(" then the left parentheses is missing , and so on.

i worked out the code for the case of " (A+B) " and it prints balanced, but for the case of  " (A+B))" it prints Balanced and Left missing and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is

here's the code:
(EDIT: I worked it out as a method, it works fine when the expression is balanced and when the right parenthesis is missing, but if the left one is missing it prints out "balanced") The problem is when it has a missing left parenthesis, the stack returned is empty, so that's why it prints "balanced" . I dont really know how to fix that case!

```
 public static Stack isBalanced(String str) {

    Stack s = new Stack();
    char temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '(') {
            s.push(str.charAt(i));
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == ')') {
                if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                temp = (char) s.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: What did stepping through this with a debugger tell you?

Comment: @RossDrew - please consider undeleting your answer.  Sure, it's not perfect, but it should be easy to fix.

Comment: Debugger is your friend but...you'll see you'll repeat your checks for its character. First ")" will print "balanced", second will print "left missing". Do this check AT THE END. In loop you just need to count them (+1 for "(" and -1 for ")"). **Result of this count must be zero and during loop it cant be < 0.**

Comment: @DavidWallace I was too fast on the trigger finger. It didn't even answer the question and chrylis hit it on the head.

Comment: @DavidWallace during debugging it turned out that when the st= ")" I popped the value and checked if the stack was empty twice..so that led to printing " Balanced" then "Left missing" so I'm working on fixing that and checking my code again

Comment: Good work.  A debugger is a very important tool for every programmer.  I did notice that the only value you ever pushed onto the stack was `"("`, so it seemed odd that you popped a value off the stack and checked whether it was `")"`.

Comment: I've been working on this for quite a while, it seems like there is a problem with the structure of my code but i can't seem to try and fix that! :S

Answer (score 6):

This seems like an overly complex approach to the problem. You can simplify this a lot just by realizing that in this case you are only matching one possible pair so a simple count is enough.

Simply scan through the string checking each character. Increment a counter at each (, decrement it at each ).

If the counter ever falls below zero then you have an extra closing bracket. If you finish the scan and the counter is not zero then you have an extra opening bracket.

Comment: +1 The stack itself, as used by OP, is nothing but a unary counter. It  represents an integer via the count of `(`s in the stack.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I think I know why down voted: the downvoter assumed Tim's answer is the same as the deleted one from Ross. Anyway, the downvote has been removed already.

Comment: This is simpler, but I didn't recommend it because this looks like an introductory PDA assignment to be built on later.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking whether the stack `isEmpty` every single time you encounter a `)` and printing "Balanced" the first time your count gets down to zero. You should only make that check at the very end (and you'll also need to make sure you never saw a stack underrun throughout).

Comment: what do you mean by " stack underrun throughout"? and by your answer you're pointing out that I should make the check for ")" as the last check?

Comment: @P.성미 I mean that if you get a closing parenthesis that doesn't already have a matching open, you should immediately mark the expression as bad (set a boolean flag, break, return, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, in the end I had only 1 condition which was checking if the stack was not empty, and I didn't put a condition when the stack was not empty, so if the stack happened to be empty I will push the closing parentheses into it and in the main the appropriate message will be printed ( I forgot to add my mm in the code above)

```
        if (!s.isEmpty()) {
           temp = (char) s.pop();
        }else{
         s.push(str.charAt(i));
    }
```

Then in the mm I'm checking whether my returned stack is empty or not and print the right messaged (balanced- left missing- right missing)